# Reading bytes from ser.read()

Tags: python, serial-port, xbee

I have one XBee router (XB-X) connected to an ultrasonic range sensor and the other XBee coordinator (XB-Y) connected to my PC. XB-X will send the sensor reading to XB-Y. I am trying to extract the bytes from ser.read() on my PC using Python.

I got a weird bytes of string consist of ">>~}3@zi167.89" on output, may I know how to extract only the floating point number (167.89 in this example)? The number of bytes are specified by setting ser.read(size=xx). Is there any alternative way of doing it?

```
import serial
import zigbee
from xbee import ZigBee
import re

ser = serial.Serial("COM4", 9600)

while True:
   try:
      input = ser.read(20)
      m = re.search(r'(\d+\.\d+)', input)
      if m:
          num = m.group()
   # statements...
```

It is working now, carelessly typed 'group' as 'groups'.

Comment: Can we see the code please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a regular expression:

```
import re
input = ser.read()
m = re.search(r'(?P<num>\d+\.\d+)', input)
if m:
    num = float(m.group('num'))
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I'm able to get m = ('167.89',), failed at num=float(m.groups(0)). float() doesn't work since it requires a string or a number. The input was set to read 20 bytes at a time. Appreciate if you could guide me further.

Comment: I've edited the answer to use a symbolic name. It should work now.